# Angular directive not updating object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that displays a tree of folders. The directive is recursive to display subfolders.

```
<div ng-click="toggleOpen()"  class="action">
    <span ng-if="folder.opened"><img class="icon" src="assets/img/load.png"/></span>
    <span ng-if="!folder.opened"><img class="icon" src="assets/img/closed.png"/></span>
    {{folder.name}}
    {{folder.opened}}
    <ul ng-if="folder.children.folder" class="folder">
        <li ng-if="folder.opened" ng-repeat="fol in folder.children.folder">
            <my-folder folder="fol"></my-folder>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-if="folder.children.query" class="folder">
        <li ng-if="folder.opened" ng-repeat="query in folder.children.query">
            <img class="icon" src="assets/img/copy.png"/>
            {{query.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each folder has a property `opened`. When I click on the element I call a function to toggle the opened state:

```
$scope.toggleOpen = function(){
    this.opened = !this.opened;
}
```

However, whenever I click this the folders aren't closed. When I put a breakpoint on `toggleOpen` I see that the value of `this.opened` is always `true`. Even if it has just been changed to `false`.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `this` isn't referencing what you think it is. Try doing:

```
var self = this;
$scope.toggleOpen = function(){
    self.opened = !self.opened;
}
```